Column contains text contains other column
Thanks in advance, I don't know much about KQL or English
    let bad_software = datatable(d: dynamic) [
        dynamic(["Windows 10 its cool"]),
        dynamic(["Windows 11 its cool"]),
        dynamic(["linux its the best"])
    ];

    let mysoftware = datatable(d: dynamic) [
        dynamic(["Windows"]),
        dynamic(["Windows 11"]),
        dynamic(["Some words"])
    ];

I need to have in the mysoftware table, the records whose value is in bad_software,but not literal, contains
Example, in this case, i need:
FROM MYSOFTWARE
windows
windows 11
Let me explain it another way:
I have a table with a list of software with vulnerabilities, for example:
"Windows 10 Kerberos failure"
"linux systemd failure"
I have a table with computers
example:
"windows"
"linux"
"mac"
In this case, I would like to obtain:
Windows, windows 10 kerberos failure
linux, linux systemd failure
Ex:
table 1:
["rod is handsome"],
["rod is nice"],
["alice is pretty"]

table 2:
["rod"],
["alice"],
["Ben"]

output I need
rod,rod is handsome
rod,rod is nice 
alice, alice is pretty

I tried with in(table) but it doesn't do "contains"
That is, I make the union with a contains, not with an IN
thank you.

You can use the below query to achieve your requirement.
First expand the dynamic array using mv-expand in both tables and store as string column. Now, cross join both tables by using a placeholder column and use contains on the required columns.
let bad_software = datatable(d: dynamic) [
    dynamic(["rod is handsome"]),
    dynamic(["rod is nice"]),
    dynamic(["alice is pretty"])
];

let mysoftware = datatable(d: dynamic) [
    dynamic(["rod"]),
    dynamic(["alice"]),
    dynamic(["Ben"])
];

let a=bad_software
| mv-expand d
| extend total_str = tostring(d);

let b= mysoftware | mv-expand d | extend req_str = tostring(d);

a | extend placeholder=1
| join kind=inner (b | extend placeholder=1) on placeholder
| where total_str contains req

Output:

